# Get records based on associations attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm working on a project where I have a User, a user has one UserSetting. I want to get the users where User.user_setting.status == 'active'. I have at the moment:

```
User.joins(:user_setting).where(:user_setting => {:status => 'active'})
```

but it doesn't seem to work, I get the error

```
Unknown column 'user_setting.status' in 'where clause'
```

If anyone could help me with where I'm going wrong that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yup, I'm sure. UserSettings returns `UserSettings(id: integer, status: string, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)`

Comment: `Users` shouldn't be `User`? Typo? And, so, in user.rb you have `has_one :user_settings`? Plural?

Comment: You're naming your models incorrectly. A `users` table should be managed by a `User` model, not a `Users` model, and `user_settings` should map to a `UserSetting` model, not a `UserSettings` model. Model names need to be *singular* for Rails to automatically pick the right table, not plural. Fix those problems, and see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry that is how it is, I just mistyped, User has one UserSetting and UserSetting belongs to User.

Comment: @user2320239 Then please fix your question to reflect your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.joins(:user_setting).where(user_settings: { status: 'active' })
```

In `joins` you should use the *association name*, whereas in the `where` clause you should use the database *table name* (which is `user_settings`, not `user_setting`).

## edit

To not receive duplicate entries in the resulting collection you could use `GROUP BY` clause:

```
User.joins(:user_setting)
    .where(user_settings: { status: 'active' })
    .group('users.id')
```

Another option would be using `includes` instead of `joins`:

```
User.includes(:user_setting)
    .where.not(user_settings: { id: nil })
    .where(user_settings: { status: 'active' })
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept your answer when I'm allowed.

Comment: I don't know about Rails 5, but in previous versions, using AR's `joins` method would use a SQL `INNER JOIN`, which makes duplicates in the AR::Relation afterwards. Use `includes` & `references` instead to get rid of duplicates

Comment: @MrYoshiji yep, joins still produces duplicates in Rails 5 AFAICT. I personally use `includes` or `joins` + `group('users.id')`

Comment: I think you should include that in your answer, in case someone in the future come to see this Q/A and does not know about the possible duplicates.